# how to maintain user picture from server?

Tags: android, web-services

I need to show picture of user in my application and I retrieve that picture from server  since my application also works in offline mode so I need to save that picture from server to my SD card , also I when i sync data from server next time If picture has changed then i need to change that picture in my SD card too how to determine if picture for particular user has changed

currently i save the image from server  as follow though I use hardcoded url as of now and  static user id

```
public class fetchImage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
int id;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    id = 1;// declaring static as of now

}

{

    new BackgroundTask().execute();
    File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File imgFile = new File(storagePath, "/Pictures/" + id + ".jpg");

    if (imgFile.exists()) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile
                .getAbsolutePath());
    }

}

class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog mDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(fetchImage.this, "",
                getString(R.string.progress_bar_loading), true);
    };

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            savesd(id, null);

        } catch (final Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    private void savesd(int id, URL uri) throws IOException {
        URL url;
        if (uri == null) {
            url = new URL("http://i.zdnet.com/blogs/3-29-androids.jpg");
        } else {
            url = uri;
        }
        InputStream input = url.openStream();
        try {
            File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    storagePath, "/Pictures/" + id + ".jpg"));
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[20000];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } finally {
                output.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
    };
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Also i've got one problem that when I uninstall this app from Device it should also clear these user images from sd card

Comment: please tell me if this question is not clear enough to answer. Tell what all other info is required

Comment: what exactly is your question ? you should edit your post. only internal storage is cleared on uninstall.

Comment: 1 how to check if picture has changed on server when I sync data as it won't be good idea to reload all pictures every time I sync               2 how to clear sd card for pics that are related to my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used timestamp to save the time when I last sync data and download files only after that time stamp